# Nested Serializer save post foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, serialization

In my project, the relationship between Product and Group is ManytoOne.

When I tried to post a new product, it cannot work.

I'm sure there are more issues with this code and I will appreciate a detailed answer, because I am new to Django and Python. Thank you in advance.

`models.py`

```
class Group(models.Model):
    productType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    intervalTime = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productType
    

class Product(models.Model):
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productName
```

`serializers.py`

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id','productType','intervalTime')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','productName','color','group')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        group = validated_data.pop('group')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for group_instance in group:
            Group.objects.create(**group_instance, product=product)
        return product
```

`views.py`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createProduct(request):
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change `serializers.py`:

```py
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id','productType','intervalTime')


class ProductInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','productName','color','group')


class ProductCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='productType', queryset=Group.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('productName','color','group')
```

Then change `views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import status

@api_view(['POST'])
def createProduct(request):
    serializer = ProductCreationSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    instance = serializer.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=ProductInfoSerializer(instance=instance).data)
```

Comment: It can work partially. But I hope it can works like this:
When user enter productName,color and group like
```
{ 
"productName": "x1234",
"color": "white",
"group": "B1"
}
Then the whole **Group** information can be nested in the **Product** ,like
{ 
"productName": "x1234",
"color": "white",
"group": {
        "productType":"B1",
        "intervalTime": 200
     }
}

Comment: @GuantingChen Do you want users to be able to create new `Group` instances in `createProduct` or only refer to existing ones to create new `Product` instances?

Comment: @GuantingChen Right now you have designed you serializer to always create new `Group` instances and not to refer to existing ones

Comment: I want users create new **Product** instances based on the existing **groups**. As I have another view to create **Group**. That means users need to create groups first. Everytime  when users want to create a new product, just use the existing groups will be ok.

Comment: Just one more question. I have tried your answer. For now, user need to enter group id, then it can be nested. But I hope user can just enter **productType**, not id.

Comment: @GuantingChen Ok I've edited `ProductCreationSerializer`

Comment: It reported an error. **products.models.Group.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Group -- it returned 2!**

Comment: @GuantingChen It means that you have associated the same `productType` to multiple groups (this is not allowed if you use it for lookup). You must remove duplicate `productType` values or use `id` for lookup instead of `productType` (as we did earlier)

Comment: You are right. Duplicate groups have been created before. My bad. Problem have been solved now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @GuantingChen No problem :). Maybe add `unique=True` to the `productType` field of the `Group` model, to avoid the same problem in the future

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will do that.